# ccMouseDragged not called right above a CCMenu

Tags: macos, cocos2d-iphone, scroll, mouseevent

I created a simple scroll view that has many CCMenu nodes. The scroll is working correctly as long as I don't drag the area above the menus (since it has higher priority).
So I solved this issue by registering a mouse event as follows:

```
        [[CCEventDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addMouseDelegate:self priority:INT_MIN+1];
```

The scrolling works with this fix but the CCMenu selectors are never fired since the scroller has a higher priority.
How can I solve this issue by getting the layer to always detect mouse events as well as CCMenu items working with tapping only (i don't want them to work on dragging)?
Please note that I am working on OSX and cocos2d 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'temporary' solution that worked for me was changing CCMenu to CCSprite and manually check for mouse events in ccMouseUp.